# Reusable Cascading DropDown List in .Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a cascading drop-down list which is used in most of my views.

Are there other methods except for creating a partial view in .Net Core with MVC with which I can reuse them in all my views?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net core , you can use [View components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2) .

View components are similar to partial views, but they're much more powerful ,it can inlcudes business logic ,the same separation-of-concerns and testability benefits found between a controller and view , and are intended anywhere you have reusable rendering logic that's too complex for a partial view .

Comment: I created a dummy project for ViewComponent. The problem is even if I filter country and state list in controller, the view does not reflect filtered data in both dropdown list. :(

Comment: You should implement the business logic inside view component .

Comment: Didn't understood .. Like should I filter my states in cshtml file?? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you write the database query in ViewComponent class?

Comment: yes, code is similar to this link.. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/